# Why can I not insert a substring into an array using splice()?

Tags: javascript, html, string, join, splice

Excuse the petty question, but this is really nagging me. I'm following the mozilla example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
Can someone explain why this doesn't work:

```
<body>
  <p id="test">
  </p>
</body>

var url = "teststring";

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = (url.split('').splice(2,0,"teststring").join(''));
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uyk2p437/1/

Comment: what do you expect?

Comment: @MattBurland I think you meant `splice` not `split`. (5min already passed)!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Whoops. Thanks.

Comment: because `splice()` doesn't return the Array you've spliced, but the array you've removed. In your case `url.split('').slice(2,2).join('')` would do exactly the same

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uyk2p437/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method returns an array containing removed elements, in your case, it would be empty and you are applying [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method which generates an empty string.

Use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) ( or [`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)) method instead :

```
url.slice(0, 2) + "teststring" + url.slice(2)
```

```js
var url = "teststring";

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = url.slice(0, 2) + "1" + url.slice(2);
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="test">
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: `substr` will be better since it's a string (I don't mean in performance or anything I just meant it would make sense)! But good answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Because the return value from splice is the removed items. Not the modified array. It modifies in place

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> **Return value**
>
> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

```js
var url = "teststring";
var split = url.split('');
split.splice(2,0,"teststring");   // this returns an empty array because you aren't removing anything
// but the value in split is now:
// ['t','e','t','e','s','t','s','t','r','i','n','g','s','t','s','t','r','i','n','g']
console.log(split.join(''));      // gives you the expected result
```

Or you can use `slice` as in Pranav's answer, or `substr` or `substring`.